# How can I commit files with LF line endings, but keep certain file types in CRLF when running on OS X?

Tags: windows, git, unix, line-endings

In our repository, line endings are all `LF`. This is good. When checking out to Windows, `core.autocrlf` makes life simple by keeping all files as `CRLF` locally, but commits `LF` endings. This too is good.

But things aren't so good when my local copy is on OS X and a Windows VM is working with some of the files (Visual Studio for the web files), as LF messes things up a bit.

So what I want is to keep the repository as LF, and locally have only a select few file types as CRLF. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure the repo has `core.autocrlf` set:

   `git config --global core.autocrlf true`
2. Create/modify file `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` with line(s) as such:

> ```
> *.js      eol=crlf
> *.css     eol=crlf
> *.html    eol=crlf
> ```

I verified this using Notepad++ - local file had CRLF, then file downloaded straight from repo host showed just LF.

Answer (score 1):

That is done using the `.gitattributes` file, which allows you to match filenames by a pattern, assigning the intended behavior based on the match.

Further reading:

- [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/), shows an [example](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#example) with a pattern:

```
    # Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
    *.sln text eol=crlf
```

- [gitattributes - defining attributes per path](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: Aren't .gitattributes files usually committed to the repo, thus making it more of a team option than a single user option?

Comment: Sure.  But there's no point in having diverse opinions about how a repository should be interpreted (that would *not* be a team effort).

Comment: That's a bit of an unnecessary absolute in my opinion. It shouldn't be a problem if say, some devs are using Webstorm on OS X and others use Webstorm on Windows. That's at least part of the reason why these git rules have been created, to facilitate variety smoothly.